# Почему не работает анимация и не которые свойства CSS3 на моб Iphone?

Tags: css, css3, iphone, css-animation, frontend

Доброго всем дня!

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не работает на iPhone анимация и свойство `transform` для кнопок при состоянии `active`. На всех остальных устройствах все отлично, а вот тут засада и хоть убей.
Проверял в Safari на компе и тоже все отлично работает.
Все свойства и анимация прописанны кроссбраузерно, да вообщем везде работает , вот кроме мобилки iPhone.

И дело в том что ни как не посмотреть , во-первых нету iPhone , во-вторых хоть и был бы то отладчика там нету на моб телефоне, а вот заказчик наставивает на том чтобы все работало(у него iPhone) и надо все это дело поправить

В чем может быть проблема ??

Comment: `transform` с префиксами прописываете? Какая версия сафари на айфоне?

Answer (score 3):

Для решения этой проблемы есть такой хак:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
    ...
</body>
```

Он включает `:hover` и `:active` на Mobile Safari

Еще вариант - подключите эту библиотеку: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

[Референс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Буду пробовать , надеюсь поможет один из вариантов